# Reading otf path from config file

Tags: vb.net, app-config

I'm trying to access a `.otf` path from `appSettings` but it returns `null`. The path works when I use it statically.

**Config File:**

```
<add key="MetropolisBold" value="MetropolisBold.otf"/>
```

**Code:**

```
Dim metropolisBold As String = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings("MetropolisBold")

chart.ChartAreas(0).AxisX.LabelStyle.Font = SetFontFamily(metropolisBold)

Private Function SetFontFamily(ByVal fontFamily As String) As Font
    Dim privateFonts As New Text.PrivateFontCollection()
    privateFonts.AddFontFile(fontFamily)
    Dim font = New Font(privateFonts.Families(0), 24, FontStyle.Regular)

    Return font
End Function
```

Any tips of why it doesn't work or what I should do?

**Update:**

My code did work, but i forgot to put the values in right `app.config`. Sorry for my rookie mistake and i appreciate all efforts.

Comment: What returns null? The call to AppSettings, or the call to New Font?

Comment: The setting contains a file name but `SetFontFamily` expects a font name.

Comment: The AppSettings returns null @ADyson

Comment: No! i'am looking for the value. Tried the link, but didn't work. @Bugs

Comment: @OlivierJacot-Descombes No, PrivateFontCollection.AddFontFile expects a file name. https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.drawing.text.privatefontcollection.addfontfile(v=vs.110).aspx

Answer (score 1):

To retrieve the `Value` of the `ConfigurationManager` use the following code:

```
ConfigurationManager.AppSettings.Item("MetropolisBold").ToSt‌​ring()
```

In your example this will output **MetropolisBold.otf**.

This is a screenshot of my code showing the value:

[image]

Answer (score -2):

Try this:

```
System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["MetropolisBold"].ToString();
```